# Fix issue with VS Code: Border around all whitespaces in lines of code

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

All my whitespaces in VS code where code is written are being highlighted and I cant seem to understand where to change these settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In settings (open Command Palette `CTRL+SHIFT+P` and search for `settings`) menu search for `Editor: Render Whitespace` it is probably set to `all` instead of default `selection`. But i honestly have no idea why it is render with boxes and not dots or arrows, maybe it can be customized by using custom themes.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably because of the theme the source was using from where I copied the source code. Replaced all these spaces with regular whitespace and now it's working fine.